# Positing search div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I want to set search results be like on picture: http://prntscr.com/62bbce (sry for my bad drawing skills :/)

But i get that: http://prntscr.com/62bbpw

this is my css code:

```
#search{
    margin-left:100px;
    width:300px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#search_results{    
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    font-size:17px;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: <input autocomplete="off" id="search" type="text" />
 <div id="search_results"></div>

Comment: Do you need something like http://cssdeck.com/labs/4hmlra3s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the width of the search results to 300px too if you want both divs to be the same width.

```
#search_results{    
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    font-size:17px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

You position it the same way as the other div:

```
#search_results{    
    border:1px solid grey;
    background:white;
    font-size:17px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 15px
}
```

Full code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raYdLw

Comment: Updated my original answer.